# With UICollectionViewFlowLayout / UICollectionViewLayout subclass, CellForItemAtIndexPath is not called at the correct time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

This question is not a duplicate, although i see many on stavkOverflow similar. Here is the situation surrounding my code:

1. CellForItemAtIndexPath - is called correctly if i have my collection view is *outside* of a UIStackView. Problem only happens when its inside of a stackView
2. I have correctly subclassed my flowLayout from UICollectionViewFlowLayout.
3. The CollectionView correctly returns the numberOfSections, and the NumberOfItems in each section. The number of items in each section is 42 (6 rows x 7 columns)

Here is what the problem looks like:  You can see it will get to a point where the CellForItemAtIndexPath method is not called. There will be no cells there. Then suddenly, when you get to a certain point in scrolling, it will just be called immediately, causing the cells to appear.

[image]

Does any one know what the error could be? This error does not happen if the UICollectionView is not placed inside a UIStackView.

**[edit]**

Ok. I have narrowed to problem down to the UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass. There is a short line of code in there to change the layout of the collectionView to horizontal. Meaning, cells on the view are normally rendered like this:

> ```
> [1][4][7]
> [2][5][8]
> [3][6][9]
>
> //But the code should render it like this
> [1][2][3]
> [4][5][6]
> [7][8][9]
> ```

I have the following code to do this (taken from KDCalendar). This code works fine, but once its inside of a stackView, it looks what what is displayed above. Is the approach for changing the order for the cells different when inside a stackView? the following is the code causing the problem (only inside stackView)

```
override  public func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    if let attrs = super.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        let attrscp = attrs.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
        self.applyLayoutAttributes(attrscp)
        return attrscp
    }
    return nil
}

override public func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    return super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)?.map {
        attrs in
        let attrscp = attrs.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
        self.applyLayoutAttributes(attrscp)
        return attrscp
    }
}

func applyLayoutAttributes(attributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    if attributes.representedElementKind != nil {return}
    if let collectionView = self.collectionView {
        let stride = (self.scrollDirection == .Horizontal) ? collectionView.frame.size.width : collectionView.frame.size.height
        let offset = CGFloat(attributes.indexPath.section) * stride
        var xCellOffset : CGFloat = CGFloat(attributes.indexPath.item % 7) * self.itemSize.width
        var yCellOffset : CGFloat = CGFloat(attributes.indexPath.item / 7) * self.itemSize.height
        if(self.scrollDirection == .Horizontal) {
            xCellOffset += offset;
        } else {
            yCellOffset += offset
        }
        attributes.frame = CGRectMake(xCellOffset, yCellOffset, self.itemSize.width, self.itemSize.height)
    }
}
```

So i guess basically my question is, what code is the fastest most efficient way to render the cells horizontally as shown above by subclassing the UICollectionViewFlowLayout? My collectionView will always have 7 columns. The rows can only be either 1, 2, 3 or 6.

**[EDIT]**

I have narrow the problem down to the following function:

```
func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    //Inside this function, I have put the following code to test it.
    print(super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect))
}
```

Here is the print out that i get

> - [0] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); frame
>     = (0 0; 59.1429 72.8333);
>
>   - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wbNN.gif) :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 1});
>       frame = (0 73; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [2] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 2});
>       frame = (0 145.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [3] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 3});
>       frame = (0 218.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [4] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 4});
>       frame = (0 291.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [5] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 5});
>       frame = (0 364.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [6] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 6});
>       frame = (59 0; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [7] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 7});
>       frame = (59 73; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [8] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 8});
>       frame = (59 145.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [9] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 9});
>       frame = (59 218.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [10] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 10});
>       frame = (59 291.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [11] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 11});
>       frame = (59 364.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [12] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 12});
>       frame = (118.333 0; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [13] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 13});
>       frame = (118.333 73; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [14] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 14});
>       frame = (118.333 145.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [15] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 15});
>       frame = (118.333 218.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [16] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 16});
>       frame = (118.333 291.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [17] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 17});
>       frame = (118.333 364.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [18] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 18});
>       frame = (177.333 0; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [19] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 19});
>       frame = (177.333 73; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [20] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 20});
>       frame = (177.333 145.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [21] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 21});
>       frame = (177.333 218.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [22] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 22});
>       frame = (177.333 291.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [23] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 23});
>       frame = (177.333 364.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [24] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 24});
>       frame = (236.667 0; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [25] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 25});
>       frame = (236.667 73; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [26] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 26});
>       frame = (236.667 145.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [27] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 27});
>       frame = (236.667 218.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [28] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 28});
>       frame = (236.667 291.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [29] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 29});
>       frame = (236.667 364.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [30] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 30});
>       frame = (295.667 0; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [31] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 31});
>       frame = (295.667 73; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [32] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 32});
>       frame = (295.667 145.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [33] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 33});
>       frame = (295.667 218.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [34] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 34});
>       frame = (295.667 291.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [35] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 35});
>       frame = (295.667 364.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [36] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 36});
>       frame = (355 0; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [37] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 37});
>       frame = (355 73; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [38] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 38});
>       frame = (355 145.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [39] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 39});
>       frame = (355 218.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [40] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 40});
>       frame = (355 291.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [41] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 41});
>       frame = (355 364.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [42] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 0});
>       frame = (414 0; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [43] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 1});
>       frame = (414 73; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [44] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 2});
>       frame = (414 145.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [45] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 3});
>       frame = (414 218.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [46] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 4});
>       frame = (414 291.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [47] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 5});
>       frame = (414 364.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [48] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 6});
>       frame = (473 0; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [49] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 7});
>       frame = (473 73; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [50] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 8});
>       frame = (473 145.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [51] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 9});
>       frame = (473 218.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [52] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 10});
>       frame = (473 291.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [53] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 11});
>       frame = (473 364.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [54] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 12});
>       frame = (532.333 0; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [55] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 13});
>       frame = (532.333 73; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [56] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 14});
>       frame = (532.333 145.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [57] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 15});
>       frame = (532.333 218.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [58] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 16});
>       frame = (532.333 291.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [59] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 17});
>       frame = (532.333 364.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [60] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 18});
>       frame = (591.333 0; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [61] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 19});
>       frame = (591.333 73; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [62] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 20});
>       frame = (591.333 145.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [63] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 21});
>       frame = (591.333 218.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [64] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 22});
>       frame = (591.333 291.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [65] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 23});
>       frame = (591.333 364.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [66] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 24});
>       frame = (650.667 0; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [67] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 25});
>       frame = (650.667 73; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [68] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 26});
>       frame = (650.667 145.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [69] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 27});
>       frame = (650.667 218.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [70] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 28});
>       frame = (650.667 291.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [71] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 29});
>       frame = (650.667 364.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [72] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 30});
>       frame = (709.667 0; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [73] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 31});
>       frame = (709.667 73; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [74] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 32});
>       frame = (709.667 145.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [75] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 33});
>       frame = (709.667 218.667; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [76] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 34});
>       frame = (709.667 291.333; 59.1429 72.8333);
>   - [77] :  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 1 - 35});
>       frame = (709.667 364.333; 59.1429 72.8333);

I can see that the function is asking for the index paths: `0-0` to `0-41` for section 0 which is correct. BUT, it ONLY asks for index paths `1-0` to `1-35` for the other section. It is missing the other 6 indexPaths. It only presents the other 6 paths when the user scrolls the missing cells well into view. Is there a reason why it is not returning all index? Is this even the correct way to detect the cells in the rect?

Comment: Does your layout have a value for `itemSize` or `esrimatedItemSize`?

Comment: @Paulw11 the itemSize and estimatedItemSize was set correctly. But as you mentioned "layout" you made me to double check my code there. The problem was in my flipping code. Normally UICollectionView arranges the items vertically, but i had some code in there to arrange it horizontally. There was something buggy with it. Thanks for the heads up man. I'll delete this question about one day so as not to clutter SO.

Comment: Or you can just answer your own question.  If you had a problem then someone else may have a similar problem and you can point them in the right direction

Comment: i have updted thee question.

Comment: As always this will be connected with frames - maybe you are asking the frame before it is correctly laid out or the stack view creates issues with the scroll view inside it.

Comment: @Sulthan You say i am asking for the frame efore it is laid out correctly. I do not understand this. I do not call the functions directly right? the functions in the flowLayout are called automatically when the user scrolls. I do not understand.

Comment: Could you post a sample project for us to debug it? I guess the problem is about AutoLayout, but I'm not sure, I need a sample project to verify my thought.

Comment: I clone the repo, open the example project, and I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Lancy my apologies. >_< gave you the wrong repo. --> https://github.com/patchthecode/BugTestOnCalendar.git  After you clone it, there should be a folder in there that says "Example". Head there and click on "JTAppleCalendar.xcworkspace".  Select the JT-AppleCalendar-Example Scheme and run it under iPhone. Simply scroll the calendarView to the right to see the bug. Let me know if you encounter anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a fundamental flaw with your `JTAppleCalendarFlowLayout`.

The UICollectionView internally relies on `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect()` to know which cells to request from `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath`. **Since you are passing the rect to `super` without modification, it doesn't correctly understand which cells should be visible.**

To demonstrate the problem better, I made a second copy of the collection view that stays in sync, but **disabled your `applyLayoutAttributes` modification** on the bottom one. I also colored the cells which are appearing too late.

[image: demo animation]

The part you must understand is that **the cells which appear "too late" in the top collectionView are not yet visible** in the original/unmodified layout. The collection view adds them only when it thinks they'll be needed soon. It doesn't realize that you're actually making them visible already.

#### So... how should you fix it?

Since your layout is so simple, I would recommend that you **don't bother with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`**, because it isn't designed to handle "pages" this way. Just subclass UICollectionViewLayout, and implement layoutAttributesForElementsInRect and layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath yourself with custom calculations.

Or, if you are really set on using UICollectionViewFlowLayout, you will need to **modify the rect you pass to `super`** so that, under the original layout, the rect would encompass all cells which will be visible under your modified layout.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation. Even my non-programming friend understood it! I will flag this as correct. I have one question though, I was trying to subclass from UICollectionViewLayout like you suggested, but it seems like it will be difficult for me... In your opinion will the code change be great?

Comment: Since your cells are simple rectangles and each row/column is a fixed size, I think the math will be pretty manageable. At least it's a good learning experience :)

Comment: I already have the math worked out for the `func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath)` function. What i am unsure about is how to get the indexPaths from the `func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect)` function since (if i subclass from UICollectionViewLayout), i wont be able to call `super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)`, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: Right. You'll just have to answer the question, "which cells *should* be visible?" And I suspect that question will be answerable with some fairly simple calculations based on the rectangle and your number of rows per month.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone wants to see the implementation that i did with JTBandes's excellent response, they can find the answer [here on github](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar). The layout was done for a iOS calendarView project.

The calendar view has 7 columns, a configurable number of rows 1, 2, 3, or 6.
The problem mentioned above occurred when the calendar was in horizontal mode.

The solution I adopted based on JTBandes's answer was to subclass from UICollectionViewLayout *instead* of UICollectionViewFlowLayout. All of the code can be found in [this file](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/blob/master/Pod/Classes/JTAppleCalendarFlowLayout.swift) in the repository. You can also sample the entire project by checking out the Cocoapod on [this link](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar). Thanks all.